# Gboard's "Spell check" does not work: why and how to fix?

Tags: gboard, spell-check

I have an Android 10-powered smartphone with Gboard (v12.9.20) installed. In Gboard, the "Spell check" is enabled. The problem is that the spell check does not work: if I type in the Gmail app "hellowx" (for example), it isn't marked with red underlines.

What I've tried so far:

- clear Gboard cache
- clear Gboard storage
- force stop Gboard
- restart the smartphone

No effect: if I type in the Gmail app "hellowx" (for example), it isn't marked with red underlines.

Any ideas why the spell check doesn't work? How to fix it?

---

UPD: It works in Gmail in "Subject" input field. It does not work in Gmail in "Compose email" field:
[image]

Very unexpected. Is it a bug in Gmail?

---

UPD2. In Gmail desktop web version I selected "Spelling suggestions off" (UPD3: AND clicked the "Save" button at the bottom):

[image]

The spelling keeps working in Gmail Android app in "Subject" input field, but keeps not working in Gmail Android app in "Compose email" field:

[image]

The Gmail Android app was re-opened. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Does it work in other apps? Messages, for instance?

Comment: Yes, it works in Messages and WhatsApp. Any ideas why it does not work in Gmail?

Comment: UPD: It works in Gmail in "Subject" input field. It does not work in Gmail in "Compose email" field. Very unexpected.

Comment: Yes, I think we have the evidence to say this is a Gmail behavior. My guess, based on other Google products, is that Gmail has some sort of it's own spell check that's expecting to run that prevents the Gboard one from processing that text. I haven't found a setting yet, but will continue to look.

Comment: WOW, I found a solution that works for me. I'll post it as an answer, but it's super strange, and would change the question to be more about Gmail than Gboard - we may consider editing the question as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail has a setting on the web for spell checking which, ironically, disables the checking done in the Android app (presumably by Gboard). If you go to Gmail on the web, open settings, and turn Spelling to "Spelling suggestions off," this should allow the Gmail app to show the red lines for misspelled words.

Interestingly, this seems to be using the system spell check rather than Gboard (see the different underlines and spelling suggestions), but will at least achieve spell check within the Gmail app.

[image: Gmail spelling settings]

[image: Spell check working in Gmail]

Comment: I don't have access to Gmail non-HTML version. Neither in Android Gmail version nor in Gmail HTML version I cannot find "Spelling" option. It seems that all these Gmail versions (mobile, desctop, web, etc.) use different UI.

Comment: If I open on Android Gmail HTML version and scroll down and click Gmail view "standard", then it opens Gmail mobile version. Very confused. Is it a bug? How to open Gmail non-HTML (i.e. standard) version on Android?

Comment: It's much easier to access via a desktop browser, but if you don't have access, I was able to reach the settings I needed by going to HTML gmail on mobile and selecting "Desktop site" from the chrome overflow menu (three dots).

Comment: Thanks! See UPD2.

Comment: This is going to sound silly, but when you set those settings in "web" Gmail, did you make sure to click the "Save" button at the bottom? It's small, and the settings don't auto-save.

Comment: Yes, I clicked the "Save" button at the bottom. I am aware of this peculiarity.

Comment: I also checked that the next time I open the settings in the "web" Gmail the "Spelling suggestions" is "off".

Comment: I figured, but always worth checking. Wild that we can see such similar details yet different results. I'll let you know if I find anything else that may help.

Comment: Thanks! Extra: I also see that spell checking does not work in Chrome for Android in text input fields. However, this seems to be another issue.

Comment: FYI: for a long time I have another issue with Gboard: from time to time the cursor keeps blinking, but the Gboard does not appear. How am I supposed to type? I don't know whether this is Android bug or Gboard bug. Or both.